# How to select value from dynamically generated dropdown values and perform queries to it in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

```
           <?php
             echo '<form class="farm" name=f1 id=f1 method="POST" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" style="width:35%;">
                    <tr align="center">
                        <div class="prodselectbox">
                        <div class="floatleft cat"></div>
                        <div class="floatleft catid">
                        <td>';
                        $query = "select name from profiles ";
                        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                        echo "<select id='selectcat' name='selectcat' class='form-control'>";
                        echo "<option value='' class='rhth'>Select Category</option>";
                        echo "<option class='all' value='ALL' >ALL</option>";
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                        echo "<option class='pre-offer' value='".$row['name']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";
                        }
                        echo "</select>";
                        ?>
                     </td>
                    </tr>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                   </table>
                  </form>

   Profiles Table
  id      name
   1     Hello
   2    Morning
```

I want to check if selected value from the dropdown is = to dynamically generated value from the table and perform queries to it.
If i select "Hello" from dropdown i want to perform some queries
and if i select "Morning" i want to perform some queries

Comment: It sounds like you need to bind a javascript `change` event handler to the `select` tag, get the `value` of the selected `option` and make an ajax request to a PHP script to run your query.

Comment: omg that sounds complicated :)

Comment: nah it's not. can you use jquery or do you need vanilla javascript?

Comment: i can use jquery

Answer (score 0):

Here's the general idea, using jQuery to keep the code shorter. Grabbing the value of the selected `option` on the `change` event for the `select`, then commented out some logic you might use to build your query, then an example AJAX `POST` request to some PHP script you have, passing the query along, with a `success` callback. It's pretty straight forward. Here is a resource on `$.ajax()` for additional options - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```js
$("#selectcat").on("change", function() {
  var val = $(this).find("option:selected").val(),
      query = { name: "", location: "" };
  
  console.log(val);
  /*
  if (val == 'Hello') {
    query.name = "john";
    query.location = "boston";
  } else if (val == 'Morning') {
    query.name = "billybob";
    query.location = "texas";
  }
  $.ajax({
    url: "someurl.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: query,
    success: function(result) {
      $("#someElement").html(result);
    }
  });
  */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='selectcat' name='selectcat' class='form-control'>
  <option disabled selected>choose</option>
  <option value="foo">foo</option>
  <option value="bar">bar</option>
</select>
```